# SVG support in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, svg

I am working on the SVG grouping. My code is not working in Google Chrome. I think it could be because chrome does not support the SVG `<use>` tag support. Is that the case?

Comment: Example code would help so much in this case... especially since, yes, Chrome does support svg.

Answer (score -2):

Chrome supports both **g** and **use** elements. And if you ask for some example, I can email u.

Comment: ...if you want some examples, u could check the links. [svg](http://mr-and-ms.googlecode.com/files/svg%20test.xml) or [html file](http://mr-and-ms.googlecode.com/files/html%20svg.html)

Comment: Please place examples in this thread, in order to educate everyone.